# Regex Expression on IDs of two lengths

Tags: .net, regex

I'm using regex on a large block of text that has several IDs that I am trying to extract, here is an example of them:

```
476iDD5100A9E110A2FA
155i6F1388BE08C6940D
3155i6F1388BE08C6940D
```

"i" is always present at either the 4 or 5th character. The strings are 20 characters if the 4th character is an "i" and 21 characters when the 5th character is an "i". 16 characters always follow the "i".

Here is how it looks in total in the line of text:

id="833i8E8BBB9BB1DA748D" size="large" sourcetype="new"

I wrote the following expression in .NET:

```
([0-9]{3,4}[i][0-Z]{16})+
```

It does great with the 20 character IDs, but the 21 character IDs have the first digit truncated down to 20. How do I modify my expression to grab both the 20 and 21 character version of these IDs?

Comment: The strings are 20 characters if the 4th character is an "i" and 21 characters when the 5th character is an "i". 16 characters always follow the "i". No, the IDs are typically wrapped in quotes.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to replace your first sentence with the first two sentences of your comment. Also you examples should reflect the possible ways the strings of interest might appear in the text, with the quotes you mentioned and, if appropriate, preceded or followed by other text. There is no need to say your edit is an edit. I’ll delete this comment when I think you’ve seen it.

Comment: Being new to SO you may not realize that you are expected to select the answer you found most helpful to you (unless none of the answers are helpful). However, there is no rush to do so. Quick selections can discourage other answers or result in errors in the selected answer being undetected . Also, recognize that other members may still be working on answers. Most wait a minimum of a couple of hours before making a selection; some wait much longer. Disregard suggestions that you select a particular answer. See this [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for your comments, as you know I am new to SO and appreciate you helping me get the best responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the regex below:

```
\b\d{3,4}i[0-9A-Za-z]{16}\b
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`\b`** - Represents a word boundary.
>
> **`\d{3,4}`** - Matches digit 3 to 4 times.
>
> **`i`** - Matches `i` literally.
>
> **`[a-zA-Z0-9]{16}`** - Matches a word character 16 times.

[image: pictorial representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cd%7b3%2c4%7di%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%7b16%7d%5cb&i=This+is+very+large+block+of+text.+This+is+also+lorem+ipsum+text.+This+id+will+be+captured.+476iDD5100A9E110A2FA%0d%0aSimilarly%2c+This+id+will+be+captured.155i6F1388BE08C6940D%0d%0aSimilarly%2c+This+id+will+be+captured.+3155i6F1388BE08C6940D%0d%0aThis+will+not+be+because+it+has+22+characters.+1234i1223ABCD01234THQW%0d%0aThis+will+not+be+because+it+contains+i+at+wrong+place.+123455i31321124W1&o=m)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `{16}` at the end to `{16,17}`, which will let you capture both.

If you wanted to be more strict, then you have to make an or to include both expressions when the i is at the 4th or at the 5th position, making the length vary at the end.

`([0-9]{3}[i][0-Z]{16,17}|[0-9]{4}[i][0-Z]{15,16})+`

Comment: Note that `[0-Z]` is not the same as `[0-9,A-Z]`, as there are ASCII characters between `9` and `'A'`.